# Show that for all nonnegative sequences $\{a_k:1 \leq k \leq n\}$, one has $(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^{1/2} )^2 \leq (\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^{1/3} )^3.$

Tags: inequality

**Problem:** Show that for all nonnegative sequences $\{a_k:1 \leq k \leq n\}$, one has $$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^{1/2} \right)^2 \leq \left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^{1/3} \right)^3.$$
This is a problem from the book "The Cauchy Schwarz Master Class".

**Question:**  In the solution, it says that the inequality is homogeneous of order one, so we can assume that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k^{1/3} = 1$. But I'm not quite sure how can we assume that is the case here. Can anyone explain to me what this sentence mean?

Answer (score 2):

The inequality is homogeneous because if you replace $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ by $ca_1,\ldots, ca_n$ (for some constant $c>0$), the inequality becomes, after some algebra,
$$c\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^{1/2} \right)^2 \leq c\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^{1/3} \right)^3.
$$
So the inequality is unchanged. Notice that choosing
$$
c:=\frac1{\left(\sum a_k^{1/3}\right)^3}
$$
makes the RHS equal to $1$. So WLOG we may assume RHS of the original equality equals 1.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^{1/3} = A^{1/3}$ for some $A,$ and define $b_k = \dfrac{a_k}A$.

If the inequality holds for $b_k,$ then:
$$
\left(\sum_{k=1}^n b_k^{1/2} \right)^2 \leq \left(\sum_{k=1}^n b_k^{1/3} \right)^3 \\
\implies 1/A \left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^{1/2} \right)^2 \leq 1/A \left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^{1/3} \right)^3 \\
$$